# Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. (fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

```
import  { useEffect } from "react";

export const Routes = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("red")
  }, []);

  const a = [{ name: "sathish" }];
  const b = [{ name: "pandi" }];
  const c = [{ name: "suren" }];
  if (false) {
    return a;
  } else {
    return b;
  }
};
```

With this code I have error like × Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

[image]

Comment: It says, `Routes` function is not a component, it does not return JSX

Comment: Not returning JSX is not the issue. `Routes` is just not a function component, like the error is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you are missing 2 important steps, the `import React` part and returning `JSX`.

What you can do to make it work is the following:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export const Routes = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("red")
  }, []);

  const a = [{ name: "sathish" }];
  const b = [{ name: "pandi" }];
  const c = [{ name: "suren" }];

  return a.map((e, i) => <span key={i}>{e.name}</span>);
};
```

Additionally I have added an [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to represent the name from your array in a `<span>` element. For the code sample I have removed your `if` statement.

**Update:**

Also based on the comments the issue is related to calling outside of `Admin` component the `Routes` component in your code.

What you need to do also to make it work to include into the `Admin` component `render` function as the following:

```
class Admin extends Component {
   // rest of your code

   render() {
      return <>
         {/* rest of the code */}

         <Routes />
      </>
   }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Importing React and returning JSX is not the issue here. OP is calling `Routes` in a way that it's not used as a component at all, `const routes = Routes()` as seen in the image. Otherwise, he wouldn't be getting the error since it's defined as a component correctly.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Totally right, thanks for pointing that out, just corrected the answer, please take a look again.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) to understand their restrictions and what they're meant to be used for.

> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.

Unlike other answers and comments, importing React and returning JSX is **not a requirement** for a function to be considered a component.

> Conceptually, components are like JavaScript functions. They accept arbitrary inputs (called “props”) and return React elements describing what should appear on the screen.

#### The minimal requirements of a React component:

1. return a React *element<sup>1</sup>* which can be anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, other elements or an array of any of these.
   *Note that booleans and `null` are ignored. Returning strictly `undefined` (or not returning, which is the same) would fail.*
2. then it must be used as a component: `<MyComponent />` or `React.createElement(MyComponent)` inside the rendering phase.

You're not using `Routes` as a React component, you're calling it as a function, outside the rendering phase.

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { Routes } from 'routes.js'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
const routes = Routes(); // <-- Called as a function, not a component
```

This is why you're getting the error.

While you're calling `useEffect` at the right place inside the `Routes` function, since it's not called within React's rendering flow, React is detecting it as if it was outside of a function *component*.

---

*That being said, since you're not explaining what you're trying to accomplish, we can't tell you how to fix it. Telling you to use `Routes` **as it is** inside another component might be misleading.*

---

<sup>1. While referred as *element* in the React documentation, it's known as a *node* when dealing with [*prop-types*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types).</sup>