# How can I return only the set-State from my fetched JSON data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm using this [API](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson) to get JSON data.

```
const FetchEarthquakeData = url => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(jsonData => setData(jsonData.features))
  }, [url]);

  return data;
};
```

The problem is when I use this function like this:

```
const jsonData = FetchEarthquakeData(url)
console.log(jsonData);
```

I get following console.logs:

```
null
Array(17)
```

So my function `FetchEarthquakeData` returns the null variable and the desired API! However if I want to `map()` over the `jsonData`, the null value gets mapped. How can I refactor my code so I get only the Array?

Comment: You're using setState in the wrong way. You don't need state here at all, just make the function async and await the response

Comment: State is designed to be used inside Components where state needs to be maintained between each render. This function's job is to fetch data, so you don't need to maintain state between function calls. You should store the results in your component, not in this function, or you can create a hook and store the state in that.

Comment: [Hooks are only useful in components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569537/1218980).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what `useState()` and `setData()` do. But in order to fetch the json data from the API, you can make the function as followed, then you can perform operations on the fetched data.

```js
const url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson"

const FetchEarthquakeData = url => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(jsonData => resolve(jsonData.features))
  })
}

FetchEarthquakeData(url).then(features => {
  console.log(features)
  // Do your map() here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

as per the documentation of react hooks ,Only Call Hooks from React Functions Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.
React Function Components -- which are basically just JavaScript Functions being React Components which return JSX (React's Syntax.)
for your requirement you can do as follows in your react component. 
idea is to have state hook initialized with empty array then update it once json data available. the fetch logic can be moved inside useeffect .

```
const SampleComponent=()=>{
const [data,setData] = useState([])
useeffect (){
fetch(url).then((responsedata)=>setData(responseData) ,err=>console.log (err)
}

return (
<>
{
data.map((value,index)=>
<div key=index>{value}<div>
}
</>
)
}
```

if you find above fetching pattern repetitive in your app thou can use a custom hook for the same.

```
const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return { response, error };
};
```

in your React component you can use like

```
const {data,error} = useFetch(url , options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in an async fashion in order to achieve what you need. 
I recommend you doing it separately. In case you need the data to load when the component mounts.

Another thing is that your function is a bit confusing.
Let's assume some things:

```
const Example = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(url);

      setData(result.features);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(data)}
      {data && <p>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am sure that the way you are doing it is storing the data properly on `data`, but you can not see it on your console.log. It is a bit tricky. 
You can read a bit more here => https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3

Adding a bit more of complexity in case you want to handle different states like loading and error.

```
const Example = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);

      try {
        const result = await fetch(url);
        setData(result.features);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }

      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(data)}
      {data && <p>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```